# How to executing Spring junit via maven?

Tags: spring, maven-3, junit4

We have a maven mutimodule project. I need to run spring JUnit in one of the modules, and it is a java project, not the web. How do I specify runtime dependencies? The project is compiling fine. However during test execution, spring loads all beans, then it throws an exception due to run time dependencies. It's working fine when I add all of the required libraries in the Java jre/lib/ext directory.

Comment: Can you post some code?  How are you configuring your test environment with Spring, show your pom.xml, etc?

Comment: I am using @RunWith(SpringJunit4ClassRunner) to load and run beans and test